# Unable to run LSTM model on python 3.7, Tensorflow 1.15.0

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I'm new to LSTM modelling, and try some basic coding. I'm getting error while adding and when fitting the model

The link i'm referring https://analyticsindiamag.com/how-to-code-your-first-lstm-network-in-keras/

Please help me as where i'm going wrong and how to fix it

Python Version is 3.7
Tensorflow Version 1.15.0

Code

```
    import keras
        from keras.datasets import mnist
        from keras.models import Sequential
        from keras.layers import CuDNNLSTM, Dense, Dropout, LSTM
        from keras.optimizers import Adam

#Importing the data
        (X_train, y_train),(X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()  # unpacks images to x_train/x_test and 
labels to y_train/y_test
#Normalizing the data
         X_train = X_train.astype('float32') / 255.0
         X_test = X_test.astype('float32') / 255.0

#Initializing the classifier Network
         classifier = Sequential()

#Adding the input LSTM network layer
         classifier.add(CuDNNLSTM(128, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1:]), return_sequences=True))
         classifier.add(Dropout(0.2))


#Adding a second LSTM network layer
         classifier.add(CuDNNLSTM(128))

#Adding a dense hidden layer
         classifier.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
         classifier.add(Dropout(0.2))

#Adding the output layer
         classifier.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

         classifier.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1:]), return_sequences=True))

#Compiling the network
          classifier.compile( loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001, decay=1e-6),
              metrics=['accuracy'] )

#Fitting the data to the model
           classifier.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs=3,validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

Getting error while running below code

Error 1:

```
  classifier.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1:]), return_sequences=True))

  ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_19: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2
```

Error 2:

```
  classifier.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs=3,validation_data=(X_test, y_test))



  AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute '_feed_output_names'
```

Comment: In your error, remove that line. It's the same line as the first input layer of CuDNNLSTM. It's just present if you don't have GPU. After dense layer, you are adding LSTM layer. The dimensions for LSTM is 3 (None, no_of_seq, feature_vec_length). Read the tut again.

Comment: Yes i got it. I don't have GPU, hence tried that line. Also, if i ignore that line and run fit. There is a new dimension error, what extra argument needs to be passed for that?

Comment: Why are you setting `input_shape=(X_train.shape[1:])` ? this is [H,W] which is 2 dims. But LSTM expects 3 dims.

Comment: Yes that's where my confusion is, what parameters are actually be passed? According to the link this is what it is? Since i'm new to this, i'm not able to figure the right code or arguments to be passed

Comment: It's training perfectly. Just replace the CuDNNLSTM with LSTM and remove that line of LSTM after Dense layer.

Comment: @AkashKumar Thanks, its working now. Could you explain why its working after replacing CuDNNLSTM with LSTM ?

Comment: @sanjanajha Your code may not be able to use GPU due to several reasons. Run it with CuDNNLSTM and then print the error. It's working for me with CuDNNLSTM too. Are your tensorflow and CUDA version compatible? The code may be submitting it on CPU.